# Semidefinite program with objective function containing a square root

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

By using a software package that is compatible with YALMIP, I would like to solve an optimization program of the form
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cr}
\max\limits_{X\in \mathbb{S}^n}& \frac{x_1+\sqrt{x_1^2+c\left(\sum \operatorname{tr}(X_k \cdot B_k)-x_1\right)}}{x_2}\\
\text{s.t.}&\operatorname{tr}(A_k,X)=b_k\\ 
&X\succeq 0
\end{array}
\end{align*}
where $A_k, B_k, c$ and $b_k$ are given matrices and scalars, respectively, and $x_1,x_2,X$ are the optimization variables. Currently, I don't see a theoretical way to remove the square root function in the objective function. So, is there a practical way to solve this optimization program? Any solver that can handle this kind of programs, or any relaxation method that I could use?

Comment: And you realize that the function is non-convex?

Comment: ...but the formulation cannot be correct as the optimizer trivially has $x_2 \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I know that the objective function is non-convex. And that is exactly my problem. I hoped that there is an optimization method that can handle such problems, i.e., a non-convex objective function with semidefinite contraints.

Comment: Well, bmibnb sort of supports it. Or write $X$ as $RR^T$ and use any non-linear solver. But first, figure out what the objective actually is supposed to be, because as you've written the problem now, any feasible solution with $x_2$ arbitrarily small is optimal.

Comment: There are also some constraints on $x_2$ so that $x_2$ can't be arbitrarily small. Sorry, I forgot to mention them. I will look into bmibnb or try writing $X$ as you said. Thank you for your help!

Comment: And I presume there are mixing constraints on $x_1$, $x_2$ and $X_k$ also?

Comment: Yes, there are.